# Right way of fetching data - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got Users and Places as two different databases where each user has may places.

I have `BasicInfo` component where at a time 1 place of the user has to be loaded.

`ComponentWillMount` of `BasicInfo`

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser())        
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces(1))
}
```

I need to pass user id in `fetchPlaces`, as of now I'm hardcoding, but how do I do with the results of fetchUser? Should I do in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` ? Or is there any other way of doing it?

`componenetWillReceiveProps` makes sense, but I was wondering what if it is a chain of events? May be depending on place id if I have to fetch some other data.

Actions :

```js
export function fetchPlaces(user_id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("/getPlaces?user_id=" + user_id)
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}

export function fetchPlace(place_id) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("/getPlace?place_id=" + place_id)
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_FULFILLED", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_PLACES_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're already using `redux-thunk`?  If so, you can return the promise from your axios.get() calls:

```
return axios.get(...);
```

...then you can do something like this (I'm guessing what your `fetchUser` and `user` might look like):

```
this.props.dispatch(fetchUser()).then(user => this.props.dispatch(fetchPlaces(user.id)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. So I believe there is no ways of passing data from ComponentWillMount because it does not receive any props right?

Comment: But in this case, every time I have to get user, places and place right?

Comment: Your props are available in componentWillMount(). For example, if your component has a "userId" property, you could pass it as this.props.dispatch(fetchUser(this.props.userId)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a thunk or a promise middleware. You can find the motivation and examples in the [documentation](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).